# Cross platform OPC UA communication for mobile platforms

Tags: android, ios, ios7, opc, opc-ua

I was looking into options of OPC UA client for ios and Android. I found out that there are some solutions available natively in android and iOS

for Android : http://www.prosysopc.com/blog/2012/02/24/otso/15/#!
for iOS : http://www.ascolab.com/en/company-media/company-news-archive/51-2011-news-flash/162-opc-ua-ported-on-iphone.html

But i could not find any cross platform solutions for OPC UA. Can anyone help me on "Cross platform solutions for OPC UA" ?

Incase there are no solutions on these lines what is the best native framework on iOS and Android for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native language for Android is JAVA and the native language for iOS is Objective C. This makes it impossible (at the moment) to write one application for all mobile platforms. Since OPC UA is platform independent, Unified Automation tries to develop applications only once with C++, and it would be perfect to do that also for mobile platforms. This works fine for OPC UA desktop applications like UaExpert and UaModeler from Unified Automation. They are based on the cross platform C++ OPC UA SDK and the GUI library Qt and can run on every platform that is supported by Qt.

Unified Automation prefers the C++ based SDK for mobile platforms since it works on both platforms (iOS and Android) and there is a high chance that it also works on other platforms like Windows Phone or Blackberry. The C++ SDK is ported already to Android and iOS. A UaExpert mobile as demo is already available for Android and a UaExpert mobile as demo is under development for iOS. See http://www.unified-automation.com/downloads/opc-ua-clients.html for Android version.

For the GUI development under Android, Qt is already used. Under iOS the "normal" Objective C development environment from Apple is used.
But it looks like Qt will support also iOS in future versions:
http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/03/qt-5-1-released/

If you want to write your mobile application once and deploy it on Android and iOS, the C++ SDK and Qt for GUI part seems to be the only option short term.

Answer (score 0):

Java is the best development language for Android in general. Therefore, the Prosys OPC UA Java SDK is the easiest one for you targeting Android. Unfortunately, Java is not available for iOS.

Unified Automation's SDK can be used for building apps for Android (on top of NDK) and in principle for iOS, but the latter is still an early beta in practice. You can use the same C++ SDK for both but you need a different platform layer.

Embarcadero is now providing [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) as a cross platform development tool targeting both Android and iOS from the "same" source, but there is no UA SDK available for Delphi at the moment.

E: details about Unified Automation SDK.

Answer (score 0):

C# and Xamarin should be the cross platform OPC-UA solution.We have ported c# OPC-UA client to Android/iOS platform.

Comment: Which sdk did you port? Is it available anywhere? I'm looking to build a demo with Xamarin + OPC-UA.